# How can i split first 2 words of string dynamic c#

Tags: c#, string, split

i need to split first 2 words of dynamic string.

```
string ex: 11 PM EDT WED JUL 11 2001

string ex: 1100 PM AST TUE AUG 18 2015

string ex: multi formats
```

I need split like this:

```
str1:  11 PM
str2:  1100 PM
```

my code:

```
int o = 1; myResults[3] = "";
    while (resultList[4].Substring(0, o++).Last() != 'M')
            myResults[3] = resultList[4].Substring(0, o).Trim(); //Time
```

result:

```
11
11
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic string"?

Comment: i mean process on multi format  ( number + AM || PM )

Comment: How about `string[] splitted = ex.Split(" ")`? Then you can get first word by `splitted[0]`, and second by `splitted[1]`.

Comment: yes worked: string[] timeSp = resultList[4].Split(' ');

                myResults[3] = timeSp[0] + " " + timeSp[1]; //Time @sukhoi191 i i use this with urls and forget to use with this =) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
myResults[3] = resultList[4].Split('M')[0] + "M";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
string a="11 PM EDT WED JUL 11 2001";
    int firstSpace = a.IndexOf(" ")+1;
    int secondSpace = a.IndexOf(" ", firstSpace);
    Console.WriteLine(a.Substring(0, secondSpace));
```

Comment: here, string a is dynamic string